# Fuzzy MySQL query using R

Tags: mysql, r, rodbc, rmysql

I am using `RODBC` package for simple MYSQL query:

```
loadData_pd <- function(namesurname) {
  lapply( dbListConnections( dbDriver( drv = "MySQL")), dbDisconnect)
  # Connect to the database
  db <- dbConnect(MySQL(), dbname = 'database_name', host = options()$mysql$host, 
                  port = options()$mysql$port, user = options()$mysql$user, 
                  password = options()$mysql$password)
  # Construct the fetching query
    query <- sprintf("SELECT * FROM pd_fizicke WHERE imeprezime = '%s'", 
                     namesurname)
  # Submit the fetch query and disconnect
  data <- dbGetQuery(db, query)
  dbDisconnect(db)
  data
}
```

I would like to change query to include fuzzy search. More concretely, it should return a row if there is a difference in one character ("John" and "Jehn" both include). So Levenstein distance should be one. Also I would like it returns the result if name and surname are in different order ("John Williams" and "Williams John" are both ok). How should I change my query to get above result?

Comment: I doubt MySQL has any *fuzzy search* support. That is an application layer solution like in R. Consider importing data as is and then filter using available R packages. And please do the research on it, make an attempt, and come back with any issues.

Comment: Replace `fuzzy searching` with what you actually mean - Levenshtein distance. Fuzzy searching is an overloaded term, to say the least. What you ask is typically part of *full text search* features and libraries.